# Text to study PDEs and Fourier series/transform

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have been trying to learn some things in PDE at an undergraduate level. I have been studying from Strauss' Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction, 2nd Edition.

I particularly am interested in learning how to take Fourier transforms to solve ODEs and PDEs like those of simple heat transfer equations such as $ku_{xxx}=u_t$ with whatever initial/boundary conditions provided. Strauss' text has been confusing me a lot since it feels rather unorganized and teaches how to solve some of these PDEs using very specific examples. I am wondering if anyone can point me toward a more general undergraduate level text on PDEs that covers Fourier transforms/series both concisely as well as in a structured way? Thanks.

Note: Particularly, I have taken/studied related undergraduate courses including ODE, Multivariable Calculus, Real Analysis, BUT NOT Complex Variables.

Comment: Laurence Evans book, chapter 4 covers transformation solutions to certain PDE as well as series solutions.

Comment: Evans' book is far too advanced for someone looking at PDEs at an undergraduate level. I would suggest Habermans ['Applied Partial Differential Equations'](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems/dp/032179706X), because it gives an ok exposition on Fourier transforms at your level, has lots of problems to try _and_ you can find the full solution manual online.

Comment: @mattos I personally don't think it's too bad - everything prior to chapter 5 can be understood without knowledge of functional analysis/distribution, which is what I consider to be the boundary separating grad/undergrad PDE.

Comment: Also PDE in general can sometimes seem like a disorganized subject - different types of PDE require radically different methods of attack. It's just the nature of how things work - different PDEs arise from all different sorts of phenomenon.